# prompt user for table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I prompt the user to enter a table name in Oracle? I want to provide a report on the table after it is chosen. I have this:

```
SELECT column_name "Column Name", data_type "Data Type", data_length "Data Length",
                   data_precision "Data Precision", nullable "NULLS Allowed?"
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = &;
```

I know & allows data to be entered by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name "Column Name", data_type "Data Type", data_length "Data Length",
                   data_precision "Data Precision", nullable "NULLS Allowed?"
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = UPPER('&tabname')
/
```

Comment: that gives an error  ORA-00903: invalid table name
user_tab_colums is the view I need to query

Comment: please check the answer again